# tmux: Bind key to open command prompt with predefined command

Tags: unix, tmux

I would like to bind a key to open a command prompt in my tmux session, but with a pre-defined command ready to be executed.

Example: pressing `<prefix> + p` should open the command prompt with: `source-file ~/.tmux/` and the cursor at the end of the line, ready to write the name of the file to be sourced.

I know how to open the command prompt with a keybind, but not how to fill it with a predefined command.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it!

`bind p command-prompt -I "source-file ~/.tmux/"`

`-I` option was the answer.

From tmux manpage:

> command-prompt [-I inputs] [-p prompts] [-t target-client] [template]
>
> Open the command prompt in a client.   This  may  be  used  from
>   inside tmux to execute commands interactively.
>
> If  template  is  specified,  it  is  used  as  the command.  If
>   present, -I is a comma-separated list of the  initial  text  for each 
>   prompt.  If -p is given, prompts is a comma-separated list of prompts
>   which are displayed  in  order;  otherwise  a  single prompt is
>   displayed, constructed from template if it is present, or `:' if not.
>
> Both inputs  and  prompts  may  contain  the  special  character
>   sequences supported by the status-left option.
>
> Before  the  command  is  executed,  the first occurrence of the
>   string `%%' and all occurrences of`%1'  are  replaced  by  the
>   response  to  the first prompt, the second `%%' and all`%2' are
>   replaced with the response to the second prompt, and so  on  for
>   further prompts.  Up to nine prompt responses may be replaced Po `%1'
>   to`%9' Pc .